# Correct Way of Creating a two way Binding of a calculated Property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a `ListViewModel` that contains an *ObservableCollection* of an `ItemViewModel` (that references the `Item` Class Model).
Each Item has a boolean Attribute *isSelected*.

I want to create a Property of the `ListViewModel` called *isAllSelected* that automatically gets set to true, if all items in that collection are selected (`isSelected = true`) and vice versa.
All *ViewModels* inherit from the commonly used *ViewModelBase* Class (,containing the OnPropertyChange and a SetProperty method).

The `ItemViewModel` is created in the `ListViewModel` Constructor and saved in the *private itemList*, which is made public through an *IEnumarable*:

```
        public ListViewModel(IEnumerable<ItemViewModel> items)
        {
            itemList = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>(items);
        }
```

I tried to simply create the properties (inside the *ListViewModel*) and put in the logic there, but that getter only works once at application startup:

```
        private bool isAllSelected;
        public bool IsAllSelected
        {
            get { return itemList.All(item=> item.IsSelected); }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref isAllSelected, value);
                foreach (var item in itemList)
                {
                    item.IsSelected = value;
                }
            }
        }
```

What is the correct way to create a two way binding for this calculated property?

Comment: The backing field `isAllSelected` is pointless when you don't use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the `IsAllSelected` property whenever an individual item's `IsSelected` property is set.

This means that you should subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event for each item in the source collection, e.g.:

```
public ListViewModel(IEnumerable<ItemViewModel> items)
{
    itemList = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>(items);
    foreach (ItemViewModel item in items)
    {
        item.PropertyChanged += OnItemPropertyChanged;
    }
}

public bool IsAllSelected
{
    get { return itemList.All(item => item.IsSelected); }
}

private void OnItemPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsAllSelected));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works with one small change, because of CS8622 (Nullability of reference types in type of parameter doesn't match the target delegate (possibly because of nullability attributes).
Fix: `private void OnItemPropertyChanged(object? sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e){...}`

Comment: It depends on your project settings and whether you are using nullable reference types.